# onclick function only loads after first

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have an html form with radio buttons. Each button has the following onclick command.

```
onclick='position(); this.form.submit();'
```

position is a function that is defined in a js functions sheet included via php at the top of the page.

```
function position(){
            var p = $(document).scrollTop();
            var hidden = document.createElement("input");
            hidden.type = "hidden";
            hidden.name = "scroll";
            hidden.value = p;
            var f = document.getElementById("quiz");
            f.appendChild(hidden);
            }
```

The position function passes along the scroll position to a page that process the form and then returns the user to the part of the page they last visited.

The first time the page loads the position function does not get written. (looking at source code through browser).

```
onclick='this.form.submit();'
```

After the form has been submitted once the function does show up, and each time afterwards.

```
onclick='position(); this.form.submit();'
```

The input radio buttons are being written with php if that makes any impact.

```
        echo "<div class='ans'><input type ='radio' onclick='position(); this.form.submit();' class='radio' name = 'question" . $num . "' value = 'A' checked> " . $row['op1'] . "</input></div>";
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: That code looks allright to me. Look for errors somewhere else. Is that "echo" inside an if? Alternatively, include more code so we can find some error.

Comment: If `position();` is not present in the HTMl when the page first loads, look at what's generating the page in the first place, e.g. sever-side asp/php/python/blah/blah/blah.

Comment: I have another bit of script: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(" . $scroll . ")` and $scroll was not defined on the first load (it was pulled form the url). Defining scroll made the rest work, not sure why though.

Comment: Why would you use double quotes for your string when you're concatenating the variables manually ? It's either "bla bla bla $someVar bla bla bla" or 'bla bla bla '.$someVar.' bla bla bla', but not this :O

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `onlick='position(); this.form.submit()'` and do this on page load:

```
$(function() {
  $('.ans .radio').click(function() {
    position();
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

That should work. You might want to be a bit more specific on the selectors as this will bind a click event to all radio buttons with class='radio' in a div with cöass='ans'